# What are GAE Text Search API Basic Operations?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I've been working with the GAE datastore for a short while and have just decided to explore the Text Search Api as an alternative for running geospatial queries.

I haven't even done a geospatial query or any complex search yet but have exhausted the daily 1000 quota limit for the Search API Basic Operations resource.

I have only been trying out creating, getting, and indexing a document. Unless I'm doing something wrong, the free daily quota appears to be quite insufficient.

So my question is; what kind of operations are regarded as Search API Basic Operations?

[image]

Comment: Have you figured out how you managed to break the limit?
I just tried to delete few documents from index and got same message :(

Comment: I've not been able to break this limit. I believe every result returned from a CRUD operation on the search API counts to this limit. For e.g. if you delete 100 documents then you have made 100 Search API Basic Operations. To me it doesn't give developers enough free limit to explore the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/):

> Simple queries    1000 queries per day
>
> Complex queries   100 queries per day
>
> There are separate quotas for simple and complex queries. A query is
>   complex if its query string includes the name of a geopoint field or
>   at least one OR or NOT boolean operator. A query is also complex if it
>   uses query options to specify non-default sorting or scoring, field
>   expressions, or snippets. Otherwise the query is simple.
>
> All other Search API calls are counted based on the number of
>   operations they involve: search.get_indexes(): 1 operation is counted
>   for each index actually returned, or 1 operation if nothing is
>   returned. Index.get() and Index.get_range(): 1 operation counted for
>   each document actually returned, or 1 operation if nothing is
>   returned. Index.delete(): 1 operation counted for each document in the
>   request, or 1 operation if the request is empty.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm asking about the Search API Basic Operations which is listed as a different resource from Simple or Compex queries. I'll put up a pic for clarification

Comment: I added the paragraph about the basic operations.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I voted it up. I'll check back in 24hrs and mark it as the accepted answer if no competing answer is posted.